# "Agreed {with / to} the {offer / proposal}"

Tags: prepositions

Which one of the following prepositions is incorrect?

> - The government agreed **with** the offer
> - The government agreed **to** the offer

.

> - They finally agreed **with** the proposal
> - They finally agreed **to** the proposal

Comment: Neither is "incorrect".  [Google ngrams suggests that **agreed to** is more common than anything else](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=agreed+*+the+proposal&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cagreed%20%2A%20the%20proposal%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bagreed%20to%20the%20proposal%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bagreed%20with%20the%20proposal%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bagreed%20that%20the%20proposal%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bagreed%20on%20the%20proposal%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bagreed%20upon%20the%20proposal%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bagreed%20in%20the%20proposal%3B%2Cc0), and it's what sounds best to me.

Answer (score 1):

Both of your examples have similar meaning: that an agreement was reached.

A **subtle difference** in meaning might be that using **with**, both sides were **mutually happy** with the agreement.

> They agreed **with** each other.

Using **to**, one side may **not be as happy as the other**, that the terms may have been **forced upon** them.

> Japan agreed **to** the terms of surrender.